# Magento observer not being triggered by event

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add a module to Magento, which attaches an observer to the sales_order_invoice_register event, but having trouble getting it to work.

I have a small script that just does the following:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_invoice_register');
```

When I execute that script from the command line in the root of the Magento installation, the observers method is triggered as expected, so I think everything is correctly configured with the module (within the global section of my modules config.xml).

However, when I create an order and then ship and invoice it from the admin pages, I can see the event gets dispatched but the observer does not get triggered. This seems to be because the getEventConfig() method of Config.php when it looks up $_eventAreas['global'] does not contain the entry I added in my own config.xml (nor any other entry for the sales_order_invoice_register event). Does anyone have any ideas how this could occur, and what to do to fix it ?

Comment: Can you share the config.xml and /Observer.php code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, am going to answer my own question.

Had been looking at it for a couple of hours, just writing it out above made me notice something more emphatically. How could it work when running from the command line and not through apache ? Configuration had to be fine, unfortunately file ownership was not. I was running from the command line with my own user, not the web service user. I had created the module config files with my own user rather than with the web service user. Therefore for the web service process when scanning the module directories, my new module config would have been invisible causing it not to be loaded. I just chowned the files to the web service user and it worked immediately.